# Android - Location Listener throughout my application

Tags: java, android

In my application there are more than 10 activities.With the help of Location manager ,it updates all my changes in the location in a db.But it seems too difficult to code the same in all activities.Since the location updation is meant for whole application,is there is any solution in java so that code size can be effectively reduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance?

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

 ... 
}


public class BabyLocationActivity extends LocationActivity {     
}
```

---

Or you could have your `Application` class implement the the `LocationListener`

---

Or you could have it running in a [`Service`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7910282/68805).

Comment: please suggest me a good tutorial to know more about Service.